# How to update the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Im new to Java-programming and I just got an assignment at school I'm struggling a bit with. The code you see below is the only code I'm allowed to edit.

The assignment is to find the word "ADJEKTIV" in a txt file and replace it with a random adjective from another txt document containing only adjectives. This part I think I nailed. But when I try to use the write-method from another class called OutputWriter, it seems like it won't take the new updates to the Strings containing "ADJEKTIV". Do I need to "update" the ArrayList somehow to keep the changes?

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 * Class documentation needed!
 */
public class StoryCreator
{
    private InputReader reader;
    private OutputWriter writer;
    private Random random;

    public StoryCreator()
    {
        reader = new InputReader();
        writer = new OutputWriter();
        random = new Random();
    }

    public String randomAdjective(String adjectivesFilename)
    {
        ArrayList<String> adjectives = reader.getWordsInFile(adjectivesFilename);

        int index = random.nextInt(adjectives.size());
        return adjectives.get(index);

    }

    public void createAdjectiveStory(String storyFilename, String adjectivesFilename, String outputFilename)
    {

        ArrayList<String> story = reader.getWordsInFile(storyFilename);


        for(String s : story)
        {
            if(s.contains("ADJEKTIV."))
            {
                s = randomAdjective(adjectivesFilename) + ". ";
            }

            if(s.contains("ADJEKTIV"))
            {
                s = randomAdjective(adjectivesFilename);
            }


        }

        writer.write(story, outputFilename);



    }
}
```

This is the method from the OutputWriter-class:

```
public void write(ArrayList<String> output, String filename)
    {
        try {
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter(filename);
            for(String word : output) {
                out.write(word + " ");
            }
            out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException exc) {
            System.out.println("Error writing output file: " + exc);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are not updating the list. `s = ...` reinstanciate a new `String`, this is not the instance in the `List` anymore, you need to set that value into the list. For that, you need to keep track of the index.

Comment: Use [ArrayList.set()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E))

Comment: Thank you! I thought it might be something like that! I will try to rewrite the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the list with

```
s = randomAdjective(adjectivesFilename);
```

You instanciate a new `String`, this is not the instance in the `List` anymore.

You need to set that value into the list. For that, you need to keep track of the index and use [`List.set(int, E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) to update the list at a specific place.

The easiest at your level. Change the loop to :

```
for( int i = 0; i < story.size(); i++){
    String s = story.get(i);

    if(s.contains("ADJEKTIV."))
    {
        //replace the value with a new one.
        s = randomAdjective(adjectivesFilename) + ". ");
        story.set(i, s);
        /* OR shorter
        story.set(i, randomAdjective(adjectivesFilename) + ". ");
        */
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved it!

Comment: You are welcome @s.sand93, have fun with java ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over the ArrayList, you can also replace all the occurrences of once using **replaceAll** method.

```
public void createAdjectiveStory(String storyFilename, String adjectivesFilename, String outputFilename)
{

    ArrayList<String> story = reader.getWordsInFile(storyFilename);
    story.replaceAll(new UnaryOperator<String>() {
    public String apply(String original) {
        if(original.contains("ADJEKTIV."))
            return randomAdjective(adjectivesFilename) + ". ";
        if(original.contains("ADJEKTIV"))
            return randomAdjective(adjectivesFilename);
        return original;
    }
});

    writer.write(story, outputFilename);
}
```

Comment: You should use a lambda to use the fonction interface ;) this would be shorted and cleaner. Also, note that you are updating every instance, you missed the condition in the original code. `story.replaceAll(s -> s.contains("ADJEKTIV.") ? randonAdjective(...) : s);`